# How to create custom keyboard short cut

Tags: keyboard

I want to create a new keyboard shortcut.  I want the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to perform the same operation as if I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.  The reason is because my new keyboard does not have a home button, and yet I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> so useful.   I went to Ubuntu 12.04 Keyboard pop up window, clicked on Custom Shortcuts at the bottom left.  Then I pressed the plus sign to add a new rule.  It asked my for a name and for a command.  For the name I wrote 'my special ctrlhome'.  For the command, I pressed down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but that didn't do anything.

How do I map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to the same key combo as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing and running `xbindkeys-config`
Then having it run `xdotool key Ctrl+Home` when that key combination is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

This command simulates key presses.

Open Keyboard settings, and go to Shortcuts. Press the '+' button to add your Custom shortcut, and enter this as the command:

```
 xdotool key Ctrl+Home
```

<sub>This seemed to work in terminal, just it does not seem to work as a shortcut... even with `bash -c "xdotool... "`...</sub>

<sub>Using this worked in terminal: `sleep 5; xdotool key Ctrl+Home` - just select near the end of some text you have typed elsewhere, and wait for the cursor thing to move</sub>

Comment: Hi wilf, even after installing xdotool and typing xdotool key Ctrl+Home in terminal, I do not get the result I'm expecting. I press Ctrl+Backspace, but still, it does not perform the same operation as Ctrl+Home

Comment: If you type some text in a box elsewhere, try it from terminal, but with `sleep 5; ...` at the beginning, that delays it for 5 seocnds before executing the command, during which time you can switch back to the box of text elsewhere, and watch the cursor thing go to the beginning.

Comment: That's a terribly tedious workflow for something used for text editing.